# Running local java/mysql container stack with EB CLI returns: nc: bad address 'mysql-server'

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So, I have a `docker-compose` stack that has 2 containers: a MySQL5.7 server and a Spring Boot application that connects to the MySQL server.

Ultimately I want to deploy this stack a Multi Docker Container environment in Elastic Beanstalk.

But first things first. I've written the following Docker Compose file for the stack:

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  mysql-server:
    container_name: mysql-server-container
    image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: packages
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
    restart: always

  saver:
    container_name: saver-poc-container
    image: travelpaq1/saver-poc:latest
    ports:
      - 3000:8080
    environment:
      DB_HOST: jdbc:mysql://mysql-server
      DB_USER: user
      DB_PASSWORD: test
    depends_on:
      - mysql-server
```

Where the `mysql-server` service uses the official MySQL5.7 docker image and the image for the `saver` service is the following:

Saver app `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
COPY wait-for-it.sh wait-for-it.sh
RUN chmod +x wait-for-it.sh
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["./wait-for-it.sh", "--timeout=60",  "mysql-server:3306", "--", "java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

You can notice that i'am using [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) to wait for the database container to be fully initialized before starting the app container.

So, if I run `docker-compose up` everything works just fine!

Now, the problem:
As I mentioned before, I want to run this stack in a Multi Docker Container environment in Elastic Beanstalk. Elastic Beanstalk doesn't support the use of Docker Composer files for deploy, instead it uses a file called `Dockerrun.aws.json`. I used [container-transform](https://github.com/micahhausler/container-transform) to obtain a `Dockerrun.aws.json` file equivalent to my `docker-compose.yml`. The file itself is the following:

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD",
                    "value": "root"
                },
                {
                    "name": "MYSQL_DATABASE",
                    "value": "packages"
                },
                {
                    "name": "MYSQL_USER",
                    "value": "user"
                },
                {
                    "name": "MYSQL_PASSWORD",
                    "value": "test"
                },
                {
                    "name": "MYSQL_ROOT_HOST",
                    "value": "%"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "image": "mysql/mysql-server:5.7",
            "name": "mysql-server"
        },
        {
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "DB_HOST",
                    "value": "jdbc:mysql://mysql-server"
                },
                {
                    "name": "DB_USER",
                    "value": "user"
                },
                {
                    "name": "DB_PASSWORD",
                    "value": "test"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "image": "travelpaq1/saver-poc:latest",
            "name": "saver",
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 8080,
                    "hostPort": 3000
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "family": "",
    "volumes": []
}
```

The [EB CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html) supports running the stack locally with `eb local run`. But when I run it, I get the following logs:

```
Creating elasticbeanstalk_mysqlserver_1 ... done
Creating elasticbeanstalk_saver_1       ... done
Attaching to elasticbeanstalk_mysqlserver_1, elasticbeanstalk_saver_1
mysqlserver_1  | [Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 5.7.26-1.1.11
saver_1        | wait-for-it.sh: waiting 60 seconds for mysql-server:3306
saver_1        | nc: bad address 'mysql-server'
mysqlserver_1  | [Entrypoint] Initializing database
saver_1        | nc: bad address 'mysql-server'
saver_1        | nc: bad address 'mysql-server'
saver_1        | nc: bad address 'mysql-server'
saver_1        | nc: bad address 'mysql-server'
saver_1        | nc: bad address 'mysql-server'
mysqlserver_1  | [Entrypoint] Database initialized
mysqlserver_1  | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
mysqlserver_1  | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leapseconds' as time zone. Skipping it.
saver_1        | nc: bad address 'mysql-server'
mysqlserver_1  | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/tzdata.zi' as time zone. Skipping it.
mysqlserver_1  | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
mysqlserver_1  | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
mysqlserver_1  | 
mysqlserver_1  | [Entrypoint] ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
mysqlserver_1  | 
saver_1        | nc: bad address 'mysql-server'
mysqlserver_1  | [Entrypoint] Server shut down
mysqlserver_1  | 
mysqlserver_1  | [Entrypoint] MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.
mysqlserver_1  | 
mysqlserver_1  | [Entrypoint] Starting MySQL 5.7.26-1.1.11
saver_1        | nc: bad address 'mysql-server'
saver_1        | nc: bad address 'mysql-server'
...
```

And it just keeps printing

```
saver_1        | nc: bad address 'mysql-server'
```

In the end, the wait-for-it timeout expires and the saver app fails to start because it can't connect to the database.

As you can see, the database service container gets initialized, `wait-for-it` seems to get in action, but the `saver_1` service can't resolve the `mysql-server` address that corresponds to the database service container (I guess it refers to the address `mysql-server:3306` that wait-for-it tries to test for)

So, what could be the problem? How can I make the app service container resolve the database service container URL? I'm not too familiar with Multi Docker Container environments in Elastic Beanstalk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a dumb mistake from my part.

I was missing the `links` property in the container definition for the `saver` app container to allow the containers to "talk" to each other, like this:

```
"links": [
    "mysql-server"
],
```

I could delete the question but it may be useful as a summary for deploying a docker stack in Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: Getting the same error here on latest version of Docker although on previous versions i did not used `links` at all.